# get results of two different function run in parallel

Tags: python-3.x

I want to get the results of two different functions started asynchronously with different arguments running in parallel.The results should be collected after finishing both jobs. All sample methods I saw was running same function with multiple arguments. Besides I don't know how to collect the results.

Here is what the codes look like:

```
def func1(x,y):
    print("run func1")
    if x == 1:
        res1=x+y
    else:
        res1=x-y
    time.sleep(2)
    return res1
def func2(text):
    print("run fun2")
    if text=="hello":
        res2=True
    else:
        res2=False
    time.sleep(1)
    return res2

def parallel():
    #parallel computing
    res1=func1(x=2,y=4)
    res2=func2(text="hello")
    return res1,res2
res1,res2=parallel()
print(res1)
print(res2)
```

Comment: Nothing is running asynchronously there

Comment: What makes any of this parallel apart from the name?

Comment: Are you asking *how* to do things in parallel? e.g. with `threading`/`multiprocessing`/`concurrent.futures`/(for some purposes)`asyncio`? Typically using `multiprocessing.Pool` or one of the `Executor` classes from `concurrent.futures` is the starting point for dispatching arbitrary tasks to operate in parallel while being able to block on one or more of them and collect the results.

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest So why there are created libraries for it?

Comment: @LinFelix I expect parallel method to do the task I want, In this example the func2 finishes sooner.

Comment: @yasharov, so feel free to use them

Comment: @ShadowRanger yes I ask about how to do different functions in parallel. Your mentioned libraries do for same function feeding multiple parameters. If you have idea please write the working code.

Comment: @yasharov: This isn't a code-writing service. You can view the docs for any/all of those modules (they're part of the "Batteries included" standard library for Python, so you definitely have access), they have plenty of examples. It's really not that difficult, but if you have someone else do it for you every time, you'll never learn how to use them. As written, `asyncio` is inappropriate (but could be made appropriate with `await asyncio.sleep(#)` replacing `time.sleep(#)`), but in the real world functions don't just sleep for no reason, so it depends on what the real code would do.

Comment: I have tested many of them. But they could not do my job. Because either they do for same function or don't return output results. so I was disappointed from using them.

Comment: the sleep function is just to show the methods have different processing time. I also tested asyncio too but it does not return outputs.

Answer (score 0):

I came across the asyncio module in Python, which can be used to get asynchronous output.

#Asynchronous output means that the program can do other things while it is waiting for the output from a slow operation.

You can read more about the asyncio module here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio.html

I hope this helps!

Comment: I have tested this library.The problem is that It is not clear how async can collect the results of the two function.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to take a look at `multiprocessing.Pool()` and `apply_async()` as I think that path is the easiest to get something working.

Here is what your code might look like:

```py
import time
import multiprocessing
import functools

def func1(x,y):
    print("run func1")
    if x == 1:
        res1 = x+y
    else:
        res1 = x-y

    time.sleep(5)
    return res1

def func2(text):
    print("run fun2")
    if text=="hello":
        res2 = True
    else:
        res2 = False

    time.sleep(5)
    return res2

if __name__ == "__main__":

    start_time = time.time()
    with multiprocessing.Pool() as pool:
        res1 = pool.apply_async(functools.partial(func1, **{"x": 2, "y": 4} ))
        res2 = pool.apply_async(functools.partial(func2, **{"text": "hello"} ))
        res1 = res1.get()
        res2 = res2.get()
    end_time = time.time()

    print(round(end_time-start_time, 4), res1, res2)
```

Ultimately you should see:

```
5.2887 -2 True
```

Comment: I added start_time = time.time() and finish_time = time.time() at the first and end of your method to check duration of the running both in parallel. it took 22.52 seconds. why it takes more than 5 seconds?

Comment: I updated my answer with a start and end time and I see the elapsed time of 5.2 seconds. If you put the start_time prior to the imports, you are mostly measuring the compile time cost of the imports.

Comment: yes I have other imports too but I have put the start and end times exactly where you did. I removed other codes and imports i get 5.35 seconds. I think this library gives whole script to each thread not just this part of code. By the way I tested with concurrent.futures library and get exactly 5 seconds.

Comment: If you run the exact code here, do you not get an output indicating the elapsed time of just over 5 seconds?